# Why do I get O365 module not found error?

Tags: python, package, office365, o365-flow

I wanted to get Outlook calendar data but the module is not recognized, constantly giving the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'O365'

Right from the first line (`from O365 import Account`) I can't get through.

After that, I've tried other packages but Visual Code Studio doesn't recognize any of them.

I installed all the packages and modules (after `py -m pip list`):

```
Package                            Version
---------------------------------- -------------------
alabaster                          0.7.12
anaconda-client                    1.7.2
anaconda-navigator                 1.9.12
anaconda-project                   0.8.3
argh                               0.26.2
asn1crypto                         1.3.0
astroid                            2.4.2
astropy                            4.0.1.post1
atomicwrites                       1.4.0
attrs                              19.3.0
autopep8                           1.5.3
Babel                              2.8.0
backcall                           0.2.0
backports.functools-lru-cache      1.6.1
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size 1.0.0
backports.tempfile                 1.0
backports.weakref                  1.0.post1
bcrypt                             3.1.7
beautifulsoup4                     4.9.1
bitarray                           1.4.0
bkcharts                           0.2
bleach                             3.1.5
bokeh                              2.1.1
boto                               2.49.0
Bottleneck                         1.3.2
brotlipy                           0.7.0
certifi                            2020.6.20
cffi                               1.14.0
chardet                            3.0.4
click                              7.1.2
cloudpickle                        1.5.0
clyent                             1.2.2
colorama                           0.4.3
comtypes                           1.1.7
conda                              4.8.3
conda-build                        3.18.11
conda-package-handling             1.7.0
conda-verify                       3.4.2
contextlib2                        0.6.0.post1
cryptography                       2.9.2
cycler                             0.10.0
Cython                             0.29.21
cytoolz                            0.10.1
dask                               2.20.0
decorator                          4.4.2
defusedxml                         0.6.0
diff-match-patch                   20200713
distributed                        2.20.0
docutils                           0.16
entrypoints                        0.3
et-xmlfile                         1.0.1
fastcache                          1.1.0
filelock                           3.0.12
flake8                             3.8.3
Flask                              1.1.2
fsspec                             0.7.4
future                             0.18.2
gevent                             20.6.2
glob2                              0.7
gmpy2                              2.0.8
greenlet                           0.4.16
h5py                               2.10.0
HeapDict                           1.0.1
html5lib                           1.1
idna                               2.10
imageio                            2.9.0
imagesize                          1.2.0
importlib-metadata                 1.7.0
intervaltree                       3.0.2
ipykernel                          5.3.2
ipython                            7.16.1
ipython-genutils                   0.2.0
ipywidgets                         7.5.1
isort                              5.5.2
itsdangerous                       1.1.0
jdcal                              1.4.1
jedi                               0.17.1
Jinja2                             2.11.2
joblib                             0.16.0
json5                              0.9.5
jsonschema                         3.2.0
jupyter                            1.0.0
jupyter-client                     6.1.6
jupyter-console                    6.1.0
jupyter-core                       4.6.3
jupyterlab                         2.1.5
jupyterlab-server                  1.2.0
keyring                            21.2.1
kiwisolver                         1.2.0
lazy-object-proxy                  1.4.3
libarchive-c                       2.9
llvmlite                           0.33.0+1.g022ab0f
locket                             0.2.0
lxml                               4.5.2
MarkupSafe                         1.1.1
matplotlib                         3.2.2
mccabe                             0.6.1
menuinst                           1.4.16
mistune                            0.8.4
mkl-fft                            1.1.0
mkl-random                         1.1.1
mkl-service                        2.3.0
mock                               4.0.2
more-itertools                     8.4.0
mpmath                             1.1.0
msgpack                            1.0.0
multipledispatch                   0.6.0
navigator-updater                  0.2.1
nbconvert                          5.6.1
nbformat                           5.0.7
networkx                           2.4
nltk                               3.5
nose                               1.3.7
notebook                           6.0.3
numba                              0.50.1
numexpr                            2.7.1
numpy                              1.18.5
numpydoc                           1.1.0
O365                               2.0.11
oauthlib                           3.1.0
olefile                            0.46
openpyxl                           3.0.4
packaging                          20.4
pandas                             1.0.5
pandocfilters                      1.4.2
paramiko                           2.7.1
parso                              0.7.0
partd                              1.1.0
path                               13.1.0
pathlib2                           2.3.5
pathtools                          0.1.2
patsy                              0.5.1
pep8                               1.7.1
pexpect                            4.8.0
pickleshare                        0.7.5
Pillow                             7.2.0
pip                                20.1.1
pkginfo                            1.5.0.1
pluggy                             0.13.1
ply                                3.11
prometheus-client                  0.8.0
prompt-toolkit                     3.0.5
psutil                             5.7.0
py                                 1.9.0
pycodestyle                        2.6.0
pycosat                            0.6.3
pycparser                          2.20
pycurl                             7.43.0.5
pydocstyle                         5.0.2
pyflakes                           2.2.0
Pygments                           2.6.1
pylint                             2.6.0
PyNaCl                             1.4.0
pyodbc                             4.0.0-unsupported
pyOpenSSL                          19.1.0
pyparsing                          2.4.7
pyreadline                         2.1
pyrsistent                         0.16.0
PySocks                            1.7.1
pytest                             5.4.3
python-dateutil                    2.8.1
python-jsonrpc-server              0.3.4
python-language-server             0.34.1
pytz                               2020.1
PyWavelets                         1.1.1
pywin32                            227
pywin32-ctypes                     0.2.0
pywinpty                           0.5.7
PyYAML                             5.3.1
pyzmq                              19.0.1
QDarkStyle                         2.8.1
QtAwesome                          0.7.2
qtconsole                          4.7.5
QtPy                               1.9.0
regex                              2020.6.8
requests                           2.24.0
requests-oauthlib                  1.3.0
rope                               0.17.0
Rtree                              0.9.4
ruamel-yaml                        0.15.87
scikit-image                       0.16.2
scikit-learn                       0.23.1
scipy                              1.5.0
seaborn                            0.10.1
Send2Trash                         1.5.0
setuptools                         49.2.0.post20200714
simplegeneric                      0.8.1
singledispatch                     3.4.0.3
sip                                4.19.13
six                                1.15.0
snowballstemmer                    2.0.0
sortedcollections                  1.2.1
sortedcontainers                   2.2.2
soupsieve                          2.0.1
Sphinx                             3.1.2
sphinxcontrib-applehelp            1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp              1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp             1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-jsmath               1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp               1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml      1.1.4
sphinxcontrib-websupport           1.2.3
spyder                             4.1.4
spyder-kernels                     1.9.2
SQLAlchemy                         1.3.18
statsmodels                        0.11.1
stringcase                         1.2.0
sympy                              1.6.1
tables                             3.6.1
tblib                              1.6.0
terminado                          0.8.3
testpath                           0.4.4
threadpoolctl                      2.1.0
toml                               0.10.1
toolz                              0.10.0
tornado                            6.0.4
tqdm                               4.47.0
traitlets                          4.3.3
typing-extensions                  3.7.4.2
tzlocal                            2.1
ujson                              1.35
unicodecsv                         0.14.1
urllib3                            1.25.9
watchdog                           0.10.3
wcwidth                            0.2.5
webencodings                       0.5.1
Werkzeug                           1.0.1
wheel                              0.34.2
widgetsnbextension                 3.5.1
win-inet-pton                      1.1.0
win-unicode-console                0.5
wincertstore                       0.2
wrapt                              1.12.1
xlrd                               1.2.0
XlsxWriter                         1.2.9
xlwings                            0.19.5
xlwt                               1.3.0
xmltodict                          0.12.0
yapf                               0.30.0
zict                               2.0.0
zipp                               3.1.0
zope.event                         4.4
zope.interface                     4.7.1
```

As seen above, the O365 module is also there.

**UPDATE:**

After changing interpreter, the problem above is solved but now we encountered another one:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Account' from partially initialized module 'O365' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Show us the output of `python -m pip list`, run with the same interpreter as the code!

Comment: I've edited with the listed information.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if the version of Python Visual Studio Code uses is the version on which you have installed O365

You can change your python interpreter by opening the command palate `f1` and type `Python: Select Interpreter`

Comment: Thank you, this helped but now we encountered another problem, the details can be found in the updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the updated question:

It says you have most likely a circular import.
O365 depends on the following packages:

`requests`
`requests-oauthlib`
`beatifulsoup4`
`stringcase`
`python-dateutil`
`tzlocal`
`pytz`

If you have any import statements using one of the packages above, deleting the import statement might fix your error.

Comment: There is no other import statements in the code, 'from O365 import Account' is the only one.